# Cannot initialise app engine SDK in pycharm debugger

Tags: python, google-app-engine, debugging, pycharm

My local appengine dev environment is not working in Pycharm. It says specify appengine sdk path. I have tried pointing path to

> google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine

Comment: You probably need a full path, not a relative one.